# Get one row for each value in xml column

Tags: postgresql, xml

I have a table, called **product_variants**, with one integer column and one xml column containing a set of foreign key values.

#### If I ran,

```sql
select product_id, options_xml from product_variants
```

#### This would be a typical result

```xml
product_id  |  options_xml
132         |  <options><option_id>1</option_id><option_id>8</option_id></options>
```

I would like to somehow select a new row for each option_id.

#### The result I want,

```
product_id  |  option_id
132         |  1
132         |  8
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `xmltable()` for that:

```
select p.product_id, t.option_id
from product_variants p
  cross join xmltable('/options/option_id'
                      passing p.options_xml
                      columns 
                         option_id integer path '.') as t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8a8ec7786a9beaeacc30386f75a6de89)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a_horse_with_no_names answer but thought I would share the other solution I found.

```sql
SELECT
    product_variants.options_xml,
    (xpath('//text()', xt.option_id))[1] as id
FROM
    product_variants
    cross join unnest(xpath('/options/option_id', options_xml)) as xt(option_id);
```

Comment: You can simplify that if you use `unnest(xpath('/options/option_id/text()', options_xml))` then you don't need the second `xpath` in the select list